# Using McNemar-Bowker test to see if two metrics are measuring the same characteristic

Tags: categorical-data, ordinal-data, mcnemar-test

I have a dataset of photos of dogs with both black and white fur. One person assessed the images by two criteria:

Criteria 1: how much white fur does the dog have:

1. More than 0% and less than 25%
2. More than 25% but less than 50%
3. More than 50%

Criteria 2: how is the distribution of the white fur:

1. The white fur forms small spots scattered through the body of the dog.
2. The white fur is comprised in bigger, not too sparse spots on the fur of the dog.
3. The white fur is mainly comprised in one spot.

I want to test two things. The main one is:

- Are the two categories essentially different?

That might sound like a weird question, since the definitions of the categories are clearly different. But I want to test if, when brought into practice, these two assessments are redundant.

For this I am thinking on performing a McNemar-Bowker test, since I have paired ordinal data. However, I am not sure since this scenario is slightly different to the examples I've found. So my first question is: is the McNemar-Bowker test appropriate in my case?

The second thing I want to test is of there is a relationship between the categories. My second question is: is Wilcox on signed-ranks test appropriate for this paired data?